# Python While Loop - Variable Not Updating?

Tags: python, variables, while-loop, python-3.5

This code simply looks for a string in another string and returns the last postion of the occurance in the search string or -1 if its is not found.

I don't understand why my variable `next_y` is not updating considering that `pos` is an input into computation of `next_y`.  My thought that is that if I update `pos` then `next_y` should also update.  Instead `pos` gets updated and remains in the loop forever.

```
def find_last(x,y):
    if x.find(y) == -1:
        return -1

    pos = x.find(y)
    next_y = x.find(y, pos + 1)

    while next_y != -1:
        pos = pos + next_y

    return pos


search = 'tom ran up but tom fell down'
target = 'tom'

print(find_last(search,target))
```

Comment: No, this assumption isn't true: "My thought that is that if I update `pos` then `next_y` should also update." You need to explicitly assign to `next_y`, i.e. `next_y = <insert something here>`

Comment: x.find() returns a number, the result of the computation when you run it. If you want to compute that value again you need to call it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't change the value of next_y in the while loop, so its value isn't updated. Value of next_y is calculated once and compared for ever (or only once). To update this value you should call 'next_y = x.find(y, pos + 1)' in the loop.

```
def find_last(x,y):
  if x.find(y) == -1:
    return -1
  pos = x.find(y)
  next_y = x.find(y, pos + 1)
  while next_y != -1:
    pos = pos + next_y
    next_y = x.find(y, pos + 1)
  return pos

search = 'tom ran up but tom fell down'
target = 'tom'

print(find_last(search,target))
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, if you want to update `next_y`, you need to do it *explicitly*:

```
while next_y != -1:
    pos = pos + next_y
    next_y = x.find(y, pos + 1)
```