# Concatenate numbers to URL in increasing order

Tags: python

I want to concatenate numbers in increasing order upto x in url. This is what i am using:-

```
i=143

baseurl = 'https://example.com/listproduct/index/21/' + str(i)

while (i>0):
    i-=1
    print(baseurl)
```

instead of getting urls with different end numbers, i am getting all the same i=143.
what is the proper way to write above?

Comment: You're not modifying `baseurl` in your loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python While Loop - Variable Not Updating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33588406/python-while-loop-variable-not-updating)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
baseurl = 'https://example.com/listproduct/index/21/'

while (i>0):
   i-=1
   print(baseurl  + str(i))
```

Comment: This still won't print out when i is 143 so it doesn't fully solve the op's problem. You should also explain how your answers solve their question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is you have defined a `base_url` variable whose value is always fixed (based on the initial `i`). Hence, when you are iterating through the loop, the url won't get updated.

What you actually have to do is update the `base_url` string for each number.

```
for num in range(i, 0, -1):
    print(baseurl + str(num))
```

If you want to create a list of all the urls, you can do the following:

```
urls = [baseurl+str(n) for n in range(i, 0, -1)]
```